# how to pass enum value as a parameter to a method in junit 4?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, enums, junit4

I am writing a junit test case and passing parameters through xml file. As i know to pass a string as a method parameter, we pass

```
<Name class="java.lang.String">Test</Name>
```

Similarly, i want to pass enum value as a parameter. please help how to pass enum value from a xml to junit test.

Comment: Sorry, what is the mechanism you use to pull data from XML into Junit?

Comment: I am using jtestcase API to pull data from xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in essence you are actually asking: how to use that jtestcase library to work with enums.

The first answer here: such questions about off-site resources are somehow offtopic.

And the second answer isn't much better for you: doing a quick search leads to [jtestcase at sourceforge](http://jtestcase.sourceforge.net/). To find: the documentation doesn't say anything about doing that.

Of course, the next step would be to look into support forums for that product; but surprise - the google group they have is only filled with spam.

Long story short: I *think* that the "product" you found there is some un-maintained thingy from the last decade; not worth looking at.

That's the thing with open source tooling: when there is only one website for it, and the copyright says "2005"; maybe you should stop there and not even consider using something like that.

So the real lessons to learn here:

A) forget about using this product

B) Next time, do some prior research yourself. You don't need other people to assess the quality of some tool you find somewhere!